# MS Access 2010, how to calculate time between two records - identical ID, different time

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, time, calc

I have a list of records presented with AlarmID, System, State and Raised ON.

One event is presented by two records, same AlarmID, first with State On, second with State Off, and coresponding time.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Alarmi_On-Off]
WHERE [Alarmi_On-Off].[Alarm ID] IN (SELECT [Alarmi_On-Off].[Alarm ID] 
                                     FROM [Alarmi_On-Off]
                                     GROUP BY [Alarmi_On-Off].[Alarm ID] 
                                     HAVING COUNT([Alarmi_On-Off].[Alarm ID]) > 1);
```

and the result:

```
+---------+---------+-------+------------------+
| AlarmID | System  | State |    Raised On     |
+---------+---------+-------+------------------+
|    1001 | System1 | On    | 16.08.2016 14:23 |
|    1001 | System1 | Off   | 16.08.2016 16:17 |
|    1002 | System2 | On    | 27.06.2016 12:14 |
|    1002 | System2 | Off   | 27.06.2016 12:24 |
|    1002 | System2 | On    | 14.07.2016 03:37 |
|    1002 | System2 | Off   | 14.07.2016 03:38 |
+---------+---------+-------+------------------+
```

I want to create a query which calculates the time difference between On and Off state for each system, bearing in mind to exclude all systems with less than 2 events (in an example above, exclude AlarmID 1001), what I tried with "having COUNT.."

In that query, instead of two records, I would have one record with system and calculated time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax (and probably performance) in Access are going to be really bad for this, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT AlarmID,System,
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Raised On] FROM [Alarmi_On-Off] 
     WHERE A.AlarmID = AlarmID 
     AND A.[Raised On] < [Raised On] 
     AND State = 'Off' ORDER BY [Raised On]) - [Raised On] AS Duration 
FROM [Alarmi_On-Off] AS A 
WHERE State = 'On' 
ORDER BY AlarmID,[Raised On]
```

Note that the `Duration` value will be a `Double` representing days and fractional days.  You can either cast it to a `Date` or extract date and time parts as needed with Access's date and time functions, i.e:

```
SELECT AlarmID,System,HOUR(Duration) AS Hours, MINUTE(Duration) AS Minutes FROM
(
SELECT AlarmID,System,
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Raised On] FROM [Alarmi_On-Off] 
     WHERE A.AlarmID = AlarmID 
     AND A.[Raised On] < [Raised On] 
     AND State = 'Off' ORDER BY [Raised On]) - [Raised On] AS Duration 
FROM [Alarmi_On-Off] AS A 
WHERE State = 'On' 
ORDER BY AlarmID,[Raised On]
) T
```

Results with your sample data:

> ```
> AlarmID   System     Hours   Minutes
> 1001      System1    1       54
> 1002      System2    0       10
> 1002      System2    0       1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to find the time difference between the '**On**' and '**Off**' state:

```
SELECT
    start_log.AlarmID,
    start_log.Rasied_On AS start_time,
    end_log.Rasied_On AS end_time,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_log.Rasied_On, end_log.Rasied_On) AS TimeInMin
FROM
    [Alarmi_On-Off] AS start_log
INNER JOIN
    [Alarmi_On-Off] AS end_log ON (
            start_log.AlarmID = end_log.AlarmID AND start_log.Rasied_On < end_log.Rasied_On)
WHERE start_log.State = 'On'
AND end_log.State = 'Off'
GROUP BY start_log.AlarmID, start_log.Rasied_On, end_log.Rasied_On
```

The output I mean the time difference is in minutes:
[image: Time Difference]

Comment: I'm ending up with a Cartesian product of start and end times if there is more than one pair per AlarmID in both Access and SQL Server.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone, I'll try it next week when I'll be back in my office.